# in the below link clade master using stanford NER package.... let me know what is the Input to Stanford-NER and corresponding Output

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am interested to use clade master tool. I am doing project on taxonomy classification and I have followed all the procedure which you have mentioned in [https://github.com/flaxsearch/clade](http://this_link)

But I am not understanding how Stanford NER package is used in clade and what is the actual input that NER package is taking and the corresponding output from that NER package to the clade Master tool.

> **I'm  very particular in understanding how Stanford NER has been used**
>   **in taxonomy classification**.

( When I went through documentation of Stanford NER and installed that package : basically it classifies the sentence into location, person, organization. how this information are used in taxonomy classification.)

can anybody clear me about the input  to the NER package and its corresponding output from that package in the clade master tool?

Comment: "...procedure which you have mentioned..."?  I think you posted to the wrong site.